# Timeouts on file uploads and downloads

Tags: php, apache, haproxy

In my company website, we allow users to upload orders by uploading an excel file. When this file is uploaded, the details are read, all the required orders are created and then a coloumn, with the required order ids is added to the users file and sent back to them.

The problem I am facing is a 504 Gateway timeout. I am not able to diagnose what exactly is causing the timeout.

We have a HA_PROXY load balancer and application servers using PHP.

How should I detect what is causing the timeout issue? Is it HA_PROXY, apache or the users browser?

PS: The return file to be sent to the user exists in the temp directory of PHP in the server but because the connection has timed out is not sent back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is `HA_PROXY`.

Got that as well on our setup: the server still finishes what he is doing (so it is not the server, and `set_time_limit(0)` won't work), the user just doesn't get an answer anymore as it took the server longer than (I guess) `HA_PROXY` allows.

If it was the server, execution on the server itself would be cut short, your file wouldn't be completely uploaded.

If it was the browser, there would be differences when using another browser.

I don't know what to do about it though as I'm not the one maintaining our servers and we never looked into it, because it only happened for cron scripts which (unless debugging) don't have output anyway.

Comment: Okay thanks. There is a setting for this in the ha_proxy config. Ill give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you need sent back to the user at Real-time , You need add this code in the head of your file .

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

And from your description , I think you can use asynchronous processing .

When the file has been uploaded , You can response "Processing" to the User .

Then you can write a Ajax Request to another url to check the file is right for download , every 10 seconds .

stat.php?id=file_id

If it ready , you can redirect the page to the download , like:

down.php?id=file_id

Comment: I was actually looking at implementing the second solution as something more long term and just extending the timeouts right now for the short term. Could you point me to any kind of tutorial or some other post that explains the asynchronous method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

This way to increase file uploading time

Comment: This will just affect PHP right? Let me try if this works. But is there any way to detect what exactly cause the timeout? By looking at logs or anything else. I am using Apache(PHP), and HA_Proxy. It could also be the browser. Would I be able to know if this happens without the user letting me know but by looking at logs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it just affects PHP. Often this is nota  very good solution though, since webservers tend to stop a script that's running for too long and you can't edit that unless it's your server.